# Passing an array using express js and ejs

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have tried many things found from books or internet, but I can't pass my array to the browser.  I know that everything is working except for that.  I can pass a non-array object, like "title" for instance and it works.  Can someone point me in the right direction?  Thanks so much!

This is my code from my express javascript file. I have also tried 'send'.

```
 if (i == 25) {
       var data = ['Erica', 'Alex', 'Wilma'];
       router.get('second', function(req,res) {
          res.render('second', {links: data});

       });
```

Here is my code from the ejs file.  I was originally doing a forEach, but took it out since no matter what links is not defined at eval.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var links =  <%- JSON.stringify(links) %>
    </script>

<h1> News to come </h1>
<h2> <%= links %> </h2>
```

Comment: wouldn't it be `<%= JSON.stringify(links) %>`

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work.  I found the '- ' instead of '=' on another stackoverflow similar question.  I did give it a go though and unfortunately didn't work.  I think something else is going on, but I'm pretty new to Web development so can't think of what else to look at.

Comment: I don't think you can echo within that script tag.

Comment: what do you suggest?